# Github-actions: Temporary failure in name resolution (PG::ConnectionBad)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, github-actions

I'm trying to configure a ruby.yml with github-actions but I'm getting this error at Setup database

`PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution`

my yml file looks like this

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services: 
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports: ['5432:5432']

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true


      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt install -yqq libpq-dev
          gem install bundler
      - name: Install Gems
        run: |
          bundle install
      - name: Setup database
        env:
          PG_DATABASE: postgres
          PG_HOST: localhost
          PG_USER: postgres
          PG_PASSWORD: password
          RAILS_ENV: test
          WITH_COVERAGE: true
          DISABLE_SPRING: 1
        run: |
          bundle exec rails db:setup
          
      - name: Run Tests
        env:
          PGHOST: localhost
          PGUSER: postgres
          PGPASSWORD: postgres
          RAILS_ENV: test
        run: |
          bundle exec rake test
```

I tried following this tutorial https://dev.to/buildwithallan/how-to-set-up-a-ci-workflow-using-github-actions-4818 but nothing it still doesn’t work. I'm not sure how I can fix this, would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

double check this segment:

```
        env:
          PG_DATABASE: postgres
          PG_HOST: localhost
          PG_USER: postgres
          PG_PASSWORD: password
          RAILS_ENV: test
          WITH_COVERAGE: true
          DISABLE_SPRING: 1
```

check `db` in your config file. seems github action complaints it can not connect to `db`

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

hints to an issue with your environment variables. This tells me that your test-script is using `db` as hostname. But your environment variable say this:

```yaml
PG_DATABASE: postgres
PG_HOST: localhost      # <--- Notice this line
PG_USER: postgres
PG_PASSWORD: password
```

There's also a discrepancy in another job (the unit-tests) which set the variables without underscore:

```yaml
PGHOST: localhost
PGUSER: postgres
PGPASSWORD: postgres
```

That might be another source of your error.

---

As an aside: If you set the key `container` in your job, then the job will be run in a separate container alongside the datbase service. They both get attached to the same network. This has the benefit that you don't have to deal with port-forwarding. The hostname of the service will be set to the key-name in the yaml-file. For example:

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: "ubuntu:latest"     # <-- The container for the steps
    services: 
      the-postgres-hostname:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports: ['5432:5432']

    steps:
      - run: |
          This, and following steps can now access
          the db on hostname `the-postgres-hostname`.
```